# How do I use an environment variables in xi:include of a XML file?

Tags: xml, perl, environment-variables, xinclude

I would like to use an environment variable in the href link of the `xi:include` node of an XML file. Currently the Perl XInclude parser doesn't support any variables but only absolute paths. Is there a method where this can be overcome?
for example, my `xi:include` node will look like this:

```
<xi:include href="$GLOBAL_ROOT/alternative.xml">
```

The path referred by `$GLOBAL_ROOT` can be changed later by loading a different setting and still the parser should be able to look up in the respective location for the file.

Comment: which "perl XInclude parser" are you talking about?

Answer (score 2):

Why not use a symbolic link (either relative or absolute)? or a user home dir location (~/.xml)?

```
<xi:include href="XML/alternative.xml">

<xi:include href="/XML/alternative.xml">

<xi:include href="~/.XML/alternative.xml">
```

Answer (score 1):

You're on shaky ground specializing a private method (indicated by convention with a leading underscore), but the author could help by providing more hooks. Assuming you're using [`XML::Filter::XInclude`](http://search.cpan.org/~msergeant/XML-Filter-XInclude-1.0/lib/XML/Filter/XInclude.pm):

```
package MyXInclude::ExpandEnvironmentVars;

use warnings;
use strict;

our @ISA = qw/ XML::Filter::XInclude /;

sub _include_xml_document {
  my($self,$url) = @_;

  # expand environment variables if present
  $url =~ s/\$(\w+)/$ENV{$1}/g;

  $self->SUPER::_include_xml_document($url);
}
```

Then pass the factory an instance of `MyXInclude::ExpandEnvironmentVars` as the `Handler` parameter.